# How to update graphic in the gui when pausing it

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

In my application I want to use Gazebo as as assembly tool, so I can dynamically insert robots and change their orientations and joint angles without the interference of the simulation dynamics. After several days testing, I found there is no problem of inserting new models when the simulation paused. But when I set the joint angle or set the relative link position by the following piece of code in the world plugin, I have to hit the play button or open gzclient after I set the joint angle, those changes can be updated on the real robot in the gui graphics.

```
currentWorld->GetModel(msg->stringmessage())->GetJoint("Front_wheel_hinge")->SetAngle(0,joint_angles[0]);
```

or

```
currentWorld->GetModel(msg->stringmessage())->GetLink("CircuitHolder")->SetRelativePose (linkpose);
```

So I want to ask whether there is way to trigger gui graphics refresh when pausing the whole simulation?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5979/how-to-update-graphic-in-the-gui-when-pausing-it/) by [EdwardC](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/484/edwardc/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 38 on 2014-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I figured it out later, the only way to do that is by adding a system plugin, and force it to happen in the event "rendering".

---

Originally posted by [EdwardC](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/484/edwardc/) with karma: 38 on 2014-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0